# how to constract a vector form a data members of other container class

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a `std::array` of `class A`, class A has a data member `num_`, I want to init a `std::vector` with all the `num`_ from the `std::array` is there a way to do it?. I know that I can loop over it and assign manually, I want to know if there is a way to do it like in my code snippet.
this is what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>


class A{
    public:
    A():num_{0}{}
    int num_;
};


int main()
{
    std::array<A, 5> arr;
    for(int i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        arr[i].num_ = i;
    }
    std::vector<int> vec(arr.begin()->num_,arr.end()->num_);
    for(auto& i : vec)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly like you tried, but `std::transform` is the closest.

Comment: `std::vector<int> vec; std::transform(arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), [](A a) { return a.num_; });`

Comment: @john it works' thank you very much, write it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

What you want *can* be done by using a *projection iterator*: an iterator implemented in terms of another iterator and a projection function - upon access the projection gets applied. For example, using `std::ranges::views::transform()` (of course, this requires C++20):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>


class A{
    public:
    A():num_{0}{}
    int num_;
};


int main()
{
    std::array<A, 5> arr;
    for(int i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        arr[i].num_ = i;
    }
    auto view = std::ranges::views::transform(arr, [](auto& x){ return x.num_; });
    std::vector<int> vec(view.begin(), view.end());

    for(auto& i : vec)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With pre-C++20 the easiest approach to get a `std::vector` populated with the projected values is probably to *not* populate the `std::vector` during construction but rather to populate it via an `std::back_inserter` (as @john has pointed out in a comment):

```
std::transform(arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::back_inserter(vec),
               [](A& a)->int& { return a.num_; });
```

To use construction it is necessary to build an iterator doing the relevant projection. It seems `std::vector` requires homogenous iterator for the begin and end which effectively means that some sort of *view* needs to be build which provides suitable begin and end iterator. Here is a basic version of this approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

class A{
    public:
    A():num_{0}{}
    int num_;
};

template <typename FwdIt, typename Fun>
class projection_iterator
{
    mutable FwdIt              it;
    mutable std::optional<Fun> fun;
public:
    using value_type = std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<Fun>()(*std::declval<FwdIt>()))>;
    using reference  = value_type&;
    using pointer    = value_type*;
    using difference_type = typename std::iterator_traits<FwdIt>::difference_type;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    projection_iterator(): it(), fun(fun) {}
    projection_iterator(FwdIt it, Fun fun): it(it), fun(fun) {}
    reference operator*() const { return (*this->fun)(*this->it); }
    pointer   operator->() const { return &(*this->fun)(*this->it); }

    projection_iterator& operator++() { ++this->it; return *this; }
    projection_iterator  operator++(int) { auto rc(*this); ++this->it; return rc; }

    bool operator== (projection_iterator const& other) const { return this->it == other.it; }
    bool operator!= (projection_iterator const& other) const { return this->it != other.it; }
    bool operator== (FwdIt const& other) const { return this->it == other; }
    bool operator!= (FwdIt const& other) const { return this->it != other; }

};

template <typename Range, typename Fun>
class project_range {
    Range& range;
    Fun    fun;

    template <typename FwdIt>
    static auto make(FwdIt it, Fun fun) {
        return projection_iterator<FwdIt, Fun>(it, fun);
    }

public:
    project_range(Range& range, Fun fun): range(range), fun(fun) {}
    project_range(std::decay_t<Range>&&, Fun) = delete;
    auto begin() { return make(range.begin(), fun); }
    auto end()   { return make(range.end(), fun); }
};

template <typename Range, typename Fun>
auto project(Range&& range, Fun fun) {
    return project_range<Range, Fun>(range, fun);
}


int main()
{
    std::array<A, 5> arr;
    for(int i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        arr[i].num_ = i;
    }

    auto p = project(arr, [](A& x)->int& { return x.num_; });
    std::vector<int> vec(p.begin(), p.end());

    for(auto& i : vec)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Unless absolutely necessary I wouldn't bother going down that route with pre-C++20 compilers.

Comment: thank for the answer but I'm limited to c++17 (that way the c++17 tag :) ).

Comment: @yaodav: the example given uses C++20. Especially when the projected value is already materialized it is certainly possible to use a projection iterator with C++17.